# How can I cancel the selected cell highlighted backgroundcolor when UITableView is editting

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I set the cell `[cell.contentView addSubview:chatView]`.The chatView has a `UIImageView`, two `UILabels`, and UILabel `backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]`.

When the table is editing, I select the cell, the cell highlighted, and the UILabel backgroundColor changes highlighted color. How can I cancel the backgroupColor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    if (self.editing) {

        for (UIView *view in self.contentView.subviews) {
            for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
                if ([subview isMemberOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                    subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I subclass the UITableViewCell，and override the method `- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated`

Answer (score 1):

```
theLabel.layer.backgroundColor = myColor
```

This works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want the cell select isn't highlighted, you can do like this:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

i'm not sure you want cancel the label BgColor or the cell

Comment: thanks charse.This will let cell not be selected.I want the cell selected,and the UILabel's backgroundcolor not change

Comment: i know, you need overload the 
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated methods, like:
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
     for (UIView *view in self.contentView.subviews) {
            for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
                if ([subview isMemberOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                    subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                }
            }
        }
}
maybe the can help you

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your selected cell to change its background color set the `selectionStyle` property of a cell to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` I.e.:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

The reason why your label's background color is set to cell's highlighted color is because  you have set the label's background color property to clear color.

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: I have solved thie question by override "- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated".In thie method,I find the UILabel which in the cell's subviews,then change the UILabel's backgroundColor to [UIColor clearColor]